# MongoDB's find() is not working for specific condition (in aws cloud9)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, cloud9-ide

I am trying to get data from mycollection in cloud9 with following query:

```
cur = db.mycollection.find({"location":"Hyderabad"})

for i in cur:
    print(i)
```

But it is not returning anything, no error also (not even in cloud9's terminal in MongoDB console)
I have already tried all the syntax available on internet/official documentation for this.
I also rechecked my database name, collection name.
**For same database and collection, find() and find_one(uid) is working fine and returning correct results.** On local system also, it is working fine.
Any leads are welcomed.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show an example of a record that you think should match.

Comment: {  
   "uid": "1",
   "description": "sample",
   "effect": "allow",
   “location”: “Hyderabad”
}   -------- something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are connecting to the right database. Try this code snippet that uses the `mydatabase` database.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({ "uid": "1", "description": "sample", "effect": "allow", "location": "Hyderabad" })
cur = db.mycollection.find({"location":"Hyderabad"})

for i in cur: print(i)
```

Result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f764a7a7a640074e9012a03'), 'uid': '1', 'description': 'sample', 'effect': 'allow', 'location': 'Hyderabad'}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried all this. Thing is if I create a database and collection through mongoshell and add data then use it in my code (if find() works in mongoshell) then _id parameter is different when I add doc through my code so it is affecting my result. But if I create db and coll through my code then find() for specific condition doesn't work in my console. This is the conflict I am not able to resolve.

Comment: I got the issue. Basically, when I enter docs through it is getting stored in different structure so find() for specific condition worked there. But in the same collection when I was adding docs through API then the stored doc structure is different, so it did not work as the match attribute I gave is nested within a string.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. If the issue is resolved, please accept the answer.